# Adding a static array to an object

Tags: arrays

I'm trying to make an enemy object in C++, the enemy works, but I'm trying to add a loottable to it so it can dynamically drop different loot objects of different ID's.

The enemy should have two int[] arrays.

The first is a lootlist with loot ids `int[3, 4, 6]` the ID relates to the item being dropped.

The second is a probability list of the perecentage chance to drop `int[50, 30, 20]`.

I don't know how to initialise my Object with the temporary lootlist argument, I can do this with vectors usually, but I can't use vectors for whatever reason in the GBA environment.

I've tried this:

**FRONTEND MAKING ENEMY OBJECT**

```
Enemy Enemy(115, 0, 0 ,0, "Green Wizard", 0, 1, 0, 0, 
            100, 1, 100, (int){3, 4, 6}&, (int){50, 30, 20}& );
```

**CONSTRUCTOR**

```
Enemy(float ObjectX, float ObjectY, float ObjectVX, float ObjectVY, char* Name, float ObjectD, int Onground, bool flipflag, bool visflag, int Health, int Agility, int Mana,  int LootTable[3], int ProbTable[3]);
```

In short, I'm trying to add two static integer arrays to my object when it is initialized to become it's lootlist and it's probability list.

Comment: What language you are using?

Comment: C++ sorry should've stated this.

Comment: Do you know how to create an array on the heap (i.e. dynamically)? Does `Enemy` have a constructor?

Comment: I have this already, but this is the way I'm doing it. I have the loot object, every enemy sitll needs a dynamic loottable

Comment: Enemy has a constructor, yes.

Comment: Any chance of making your code readable